# large image size problems

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I am loading images of size 1800x1300 in UIImage.(getting the images from server..)then i am adding that images into Uiscrollview.while scrolling my images ,the app getting crashed.is it a the image size issue.....?thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be around 9MB on the device memory then I think that it's not impossibile to handle it within an iOS app (even with an old device). It depends on the rest of your app and to better manage the memory to let the app to free some space when the image comes.

Comment: Your image is so big because you need this size to show some details in your `UIScrollView` or just becase you get it as is? Because if you don't need that size, you can resize the image on the server side before to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely scale your images down, significantly, especially for the iPhone screen size.

You should also compress your images as much as you can without affecting the quality. Your image, I am assuming is somewhere around 1.5MB - 2MB, so that will use up an extreme amount if memory, and cause your device to crash every time.

Comment: ya.thank u.. but how can i scale my images....? using                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();..........?

Comment: No, you need to do it in a graphics editor, I would suggest `Preview`, Mac OS X's built in image editor.

Comment: but am getting the images from the web server.. how can i edit using "Preview"....?

Comment: The images are on the server that you are loading into your UIScrollView? If so, then you need to specify that in your question.

Comment: sorry.. am getting the images from the server..how can i resize it..?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]; 
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]],0.5);
UIImage *compressedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:mgData];
```

Comment: @Manjunath: Thanks..but am getting the PNG images from server..what can i do..?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether u r getting png or jpeg. see the edited answer.

Comment: The problem is that if the app crashed when you try to load it, if you try to "compress" it on the client side, you will always get the crash because to resize the image, you still need to load it into memory...

Comment: yes.. after compressing , i loaded it.. still it crashing...any other way..?